# What Does A Letter Delimiter in a date String Do (Besides Delimit)?

Tags: bash, date

I'm using `bash` 4.1.  I am using a letter to delimit the date and the time fields of a date string to be converted by `date`.  It appears that each letter causes a different value (from -5 to +18) to be added to the time specified. But note that `J` results in an error.  I cannot find an explanation for this behaviour in either the `man` or the `info` pages.  Can someone enlighten me?

```
$ date -d 2014-01-01A00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 19:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01B00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 20:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01C00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 21:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01D00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 22:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01E00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 23:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01F00:00:00
Wed Jan  1 00:00:00 CST 2014
$ date -d 2014-01-01G00:00:00
Wed Jan  1 01:00:00 CST 2014
$ date -d 2014-01-01H00:00:00
Wed Jan  1 02:00:00 CST 2014
$ date -d 2014-01-01I00:00:00
Wed Jan  1 03:00:00 CST 2014
$ date -d 2014-01-01J00:00:00
date: invalid date `2014-01-01J00:00:00'
$ date -d 2014-01-01K00:00:00
Wed Jan  1 04:00:00 CST 2014
$ date -d 2014-01-01L00:00:00
Wed Jan  1 05:00:00 CST 2014
$ date -d 2014-01-01M00:00:00
Wed Jan  1 06:00:00 CST 2014
$ date -d 2014-01-01N00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 17:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01O00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 16:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01P00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 15:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01Q00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 14:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01R00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 13:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01S00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 12:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01T00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 11:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01U00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 10:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01V00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 09:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01W00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 08:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01X00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 07:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01Y00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 06:00:00 CST 2013
$ date -d 2014-01-01Z00:00:00
Tue Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 2013
```

Comment: @GIJoe It doesn't seem to be related to `TZ`.  Would be worthwhile to dig into the sources.

Comment: @CPRitter don't mess up with the formatting once somebody has fixed it.

Comment: @devnull I guess we were fixing it simultaneously.

Comment: @devnull: It is related to timezones - military time zones.. see my research. I looked at the code in GNU coreutils as well.

Comment: The `bash` version doesn't come into play here, but the version of your `date` utility might - looks like you're using GNU `date` (the specific version can be found with `date --version`).

Comment: @CPRitter: Does the command with `T` really NOT give you the LOCAL time, i.e., the same time as input? If so, I'm curious what platform you're on and the specific version of your `date` utility is.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the letters sorted by their associated time:

```
YXWVUTSRQPON Z ABCDEFGHIKLM
```

I highlighted `Z` because this is (in your example) Wed Jan  1 00:00:00 **GMT** 2014. A-M represent timezones west (later) than GMT, N-Y timezones east (later). so you get GMT, 12 timezones east and 12 west, which makes 25. J just happens to be the letter that was left out, for whatever reason.

Comment: I guess that explains the behavior, but I don't have any sources. If an answer with references comes up, make sure you accept that one.

Comment: Here's wikipedia on the subject ..[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautical_time)

Comment: Still I find it disturbing that neither `man` nor `info` seem to mention this.

Comment: [Another reference](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/military/) on timeanddate.com ; it is only disturbing when you consider the fact that documentation comes after coding. It may have simply slipped someone's mind.

Comment: It's related to military time. See my answer.

Comment: Local time is Juliet. I used to be in the military and we used J on our times often. It's just short hand so you don't have to know what timezone you are in or worry about..everyone just assumes

Comment: @CPRitter: It's not disturbing because date follows RFC 822/2822

Answer (score 4):

GNU `date` follows RFC 822 or ISO 8601. In RFC 822 (obsolete), as described in the superseding document [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), military time zones were defined:

> The 1 character military time zones were defined in a non-standard way
>   in [RFC822] and are therefore unpredictable in their meaning. The
>   original definitions of the military zones "A" through "I" are
>   equivalent to "+0100" through "+0900" respectively; "K", "L", and "M"
>   are equivalent to "+1000", "+1100", and "+1200" respectively; "N"
>   through "Y" are equivalent to "-0100" through "-1200" respectively;
>   and "Z" is equivalent to "+0000". However, because of the error in
>   [RFC822], they SHOULD all be considered equivalent to "-0000" unless
>   there is out-of-band information confirming their meaning.

In RFC 822, this was known as the "hour zone". The comment in RFC 822 calls it this and defines it as either "ANSI or Military".

From [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt):

> The  military  standard uses  a  single  character for each zone.  "Z"
>   is Universal Time. "A" indicates one hour earlier, and "M" indicates
>   12  hours  earlier;  "N"  is  one  hour  later, and "Y" is 12 hours
>   later.  The letter "J" is not used.

This all makes sense because it is likely that RFC 822 was written around the time of ARPANET and ARPANET came out of DoD circles.

Here is a [list of military time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones).

By the way, Local time is specifically designated in the military as zone J or "Juliet".

Comment: Helpful, thanks; in what way was the RFC 822 definition non-standard/erroneous? Given that `T` is just a _literal_ separator in ISO 8601, how does GNU `date` decide whether to interpret it as that (and thus the time as _local_) or as  military time zone `UTC-07:00`?

Comment: @mklement0: If it has a T and follows ISO 8601, then it probably parses it as ISO 8601. RFC822 looks slightly different it appears

Comment: @mklement0: I don't know what error they are referring to in RFC822. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: ISO 8601 Combined Date and Time: 2014-02-17T08:22:10+00:00<BR>
2014-02-17T08:22:10Z

Comment: Yes, with a time-zone spec it becomes unambiguous; without one, though, there is ambiguity, and on my Ubuntu 12.04 system (GNU date 8.13), the behavior is inconsistent: 'T' seems to be be interpreted as ISO 8601 (local time) rather than RFC 822 (UTC-7), whereas other letters are interpreted according to RFC 822.

Comment: @mklement0: That may have been the point of RFC2822, but I can't be sure. I doubt many rely on that date format.

Comment: RFCs 822/2822 don't seem to mention formats similar to ISO 8601, so I wonder if implementing this curious mix was decided on as a non-standard format by the GNU date implementers; that said - to take your statement further: probably best to stay away from this format.

Comment: @mklement0: date supports it, but that's where my knowledge stops